# Visibility of a function's return value after a call to fork()

Tags: c, fork, child-process

When using `fork()` to create a new child process, we get a `pid_t` back that indicates whether we are in the child process (`pid == 0`) or parent process (`pid > 0`) after the call to `fork()` finishes. I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around that in general, but specifically struggle to find an answer to the following question:

- When wrapping a call to `fork()` in a function, will the calling code of that function (ever) see return values from within the *child* potion of the code after `fork()`?

To illustrate, see the following function I wrote. I'm not sure if the calling process/code will ever receive one of the `-1` return values that could be returned from within the `else if (pid == 0) { ... }` part of the code.

```
/*
 * Opens the process `cmd` similar to popen() but does not invoke a shell.
 * Instead, wordexp() is used to expand the given command, if necessary.
 * If successful, the process id of the new process is being returned and the 
 * given FILE pointers are set to streams that correspond to pipes for reading 
 * and writing to the child process, accordingly. Hand in NULL for pipes that
 * should not be used. On error, -1 is returned.
 */
pid_t popen_noshell(const char *cmd, FILE **out, FILE **err, FILE **in)
{
    if (!cmd || !strlen(cmd)) return -1;

    // 0 = read end of pipes, 1 = write end of pipes
    int pipe_stdout[2];
    int pipe_stderr[2];
    int pipe_stdin[2];

    if (out && (pipe(pipe_stdout) < 0)) return -1;
    if (err && (pipe(pipe_stderr) < 0)) return -1;
    if (in  && (pipe(pipe_stdin)  < 0)) return -1;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) // child
    {    
        // redirect stdout to the write end of this pipe
        if (out)
        {
            if (dup2(pipe_stdout[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) return -1;
            close(pipe_stdout[0]); // child doesn't need read end
        }
        // redirect stderr to the write end of this pipe
        if (err)
        {
            if (dup2(pipe_stderr[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1) return -1;
            close(pipe_stderr[0]); // child doesn't need read end
        }
        // redirect stdin to the read end of this pipe
        if (in)
        {
            if (dup2(pipe_stdin[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) return -1;
            close(pipe_stdin[1]); // child doesn't need write end
        }

        wordexp_t p;
        if (wordexp(cmd, &p, 0) != 0) return -1;

        execvp(p.we_wordv[0], p.we_wordv);
        _exit(1);
    }
    else // parent
    {
        if (out)
        {
            close(pipe_stdout[1]); // parent doesn't need write end
            *out = fdopen(pipe_stdout[0], "r");
        }
        if (err)
        {
            close(pipe_stderr[1]); // parent doesn't need write end
            *err = fdopen(pipe_stderr[0], "r");
        }
        if (in)
        {
            close(pipe_stdin[0]); // parent doesn't need read end
            *in = fdopen(pipe_stdin[1], "w");
        }
        return pid;
    }
}
```

Comment: TLDR... there will be two `return`s: one from the parent process, another from the child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork` copies the whole call stack, so if one of those `return -1` statements are executed in the child, it will be returned to the caller of `popen_noshell` in the child (as well as in the parent). This is probably not what you want, and they should probably be replaced with `_exit(-1)`

Comment: To clarify, (a) both parent _and_ child will get the `-1` return from within the child potion and (b) I should replace the `return -1;` in the child potion with `_exit(-1);` as otherwise, the child process would continue to run; is that correct? Does that mean I should use `_exit(-1); return -1;` so that the child terminates _and_ the parent can check if the child was executed successfully, or would a `return` after `_exit()` never be reached?

Comment: `return -1` in the child will jump to the caller in the child process, where the parent will have already jumped with `return pid`. So `popen_noshell` will return in both of the processes (like `fork` itself), whereas you expect it to only return in the parent. `_exit(-1); return -1;` is redundant.

Comment: I think I do understand now. But: say one of the calls to `dup2()` fails in the child and I replace the `return -1;` with `_exit(-1);`, how would the _parent process_ calling code ever learn that the child process couldn't be executed successfully? Maybe there is no way?

Comment: @domsson You could do something like have the first byte in the pipe be whether the setup was successful and wait on that (You still need to `_exit`)

Comment: Gotcha. Probably best to just "let the child be the child", in other words I'll just add to the comment/documentation that the `-1` return value only indicates a failure before or during `fork()` and doesn't make any promises as to whether the child ever managed to `exec()` successfully.

Comment: @domsson: the parent gets the final status code from its child when it calls `wait/waitpid`.